# Access SQL code

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
CREATE VIEW ItemOrder AS
    SELECT  Item.ItemNum, Description, Price, OrderNum, OrderDate,
     NumOrdered, QuotedPrice
    FROM Item, OrderLine, Orders
    WHERE Item.ItemNum = OrderLine.ItemNum
    AND Orders.OrderNum = OrderLine.OrderNum;
```

I put this in SQL code and says it 
"syntax error in Create Table" 
I am making a view of a table; 
help please

Comment: The error is not referring to this code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a View in ms-access. A simple Select query should do. It can be used in other queries as well.

> The Microsoft Access database engine does not support the use of
>   CREATE VIEW, or any of the DDL statements, with non-Microsoft Access
>   database engine databases.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836312.aspx